# Draw line on UIView with CAGradientLayer as backing store

Tags: ios, uiview, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

I have created a `UIView` subclass which uses a `CAGradientLayer` for its layer. This is working fine. Now I want to draw a line at the end of the gradient (used as separator). I thought I can use the `drawRect` method for this:

```
public class GradientView : UIView
{
    // accessors
    private CAGradientLayer gradientLayer {
        // read-only
        get { return (CAGradientLayer)this.Layer; }
    }

    public CGColor[] Colors {
        // set the colors of the gradient layer
        get { return this.gradientLayer.Colors; }
        set { this.gradientLayer.Colors = value; }
    }

    [Export ("layerClass")]
    public static Class LayerClass ()
    {
        // use a different Core Animation layer for its backing store
        // normally a CALayer is used for a UIView
        return new Class (typeof(CAGradientLayer));
    }

    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {

        PointF pointA = new PointF (0, rect.Height);
        PointF pointB = new PointF (rect.Width, rect.Height);
        CAShapeLayer line = new CAShapeLayer ();
        UIBezierPath linePath = new UIBezierPath ();
        linePath.MoveTo (pointA);
        linePath.AddLineTo(pointB);
        line.Path = linePath.CGPath;
        line.FillColor = null;
        line.Opacity = 1.0f;
        line.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;

        this.gradientLayer.AddSublayer (line);

        base.Draw (rect);
    }
}
```

But I get a black background. Can I use `drawRect` for that? Or how do I add a line on it?

I'm using C# as language but you can provide your solution in Objective-C as well. Auto Layout determines the size of the `GradientView` and my old solution also adapted to orientation changes.

**Edit:**

I tried what Cyrille said:

```
public class GradientView : UIView
{
    // accessors
    private CAShapeLayer line;

    private CAGradientLayer gradientLayer {
        // read-only
        get { return (CAGradientLayer)this.Layer; }
    }

    public CGColor[] Colors {
        // set the colors of the gradient layer
        get { return this.gradientLayer.Colors; }
        set { this.gradientLayer.Colors = value; }
    }

    public GradientView()
    {
        PointF pointA = new PointF (0, this.Bounds.Height);
        PointF pointB = new PointF (this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
        line = new CAShapeLayer ();
        UIBezierPath linePath = new UIBezierPath ();
        linePath.MoveTo (pointA);
        linePath.AddLineTo(pointB);
        line.Path = linePath.CGPath;
        line.FillColor = null;
        line.Opacity = 1.0f;
        line.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        line.LineWidth = 1.0f;

        this.gradientLayer.AddSublayer (line);
    }

    [Export ("layerClass")]
    public static Class LayerClass ()
    {
        // use a different Core Animation layer for its backing store
        // normally a CALayer is used for a UIView
        return new Class (typeof(CAGradientLayer));
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        PointF pointA = new PointF (0, this.Bounds.Height-2);
        PointF pointB = new PointF (this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height-2);
        UIBezierPath linePath = new UIBezierPath ();
        linePath.MoveTo (pointA);
        linePath.AddLineTo(pointB);

        line.Path = linePath.CGPath;

        base.LayoutSubviews ();
    }
}
```

This seems to do what I want except that the line is not a thin hairline. Is `CAShapeLayer` inappropriate for this?

**Solution:**

Of course it would be possible to use `CAShapeLayer`, but if I have to setup things in `drawRect`, then I completely draw my line there. Now the solution for me does look like the following:

```
public class GradientView : UIView
{
    // accessors
    private CAShapeLayer line;

    private CAGradientLayer gradientLayer {
        // read-only
        get { return (CAGradientLayer)this.Layer; }
    }

    public CGColor[] Colors {
        // set the colors of the gradient layer
        get { return this.gradientLayer.Colors; }
        set { this.gradientLayer.Colors = value; }
    }

    public GradientView()
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    }

    [Export ("layerClass")]
    public static Class LayerClass ()
    {
        // use a different Core Animation layer for its backing store
        // normally a CALayer is used for a UIView
        return new Class (typeof(CAGradientLayer));
    }

    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        // get graphics context
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

        // start point
        context.MoveTo (0, rect.Height);

        // end point
        context.AddLineToPoint (rect.Width, rect.Height);

        context.SetLineWidth (1.0f);

        context.SetShouldAntialias(false);

        // draw the path
        context.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CAGradientLayer` as the backing layer of your view does not prevent you from adding another `CAShapeLayer` inside your view upon initialization. Then you can use this shape layer to draw your straight line, by setting its `path` property accordingly (and recalculate it any time the bounds change, in `-layoutSubviews`, to react correctly to orientation/layout changes).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you said and it works. One question though: How can I draw a thin harline with `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: Many questions on SO already address this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515451/draw-a-line-with-a-calayer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515451/draw-a-line-with-a-calayer …

Comment: Another question: Why does the `UIView` get a black background when I implement `drawRect`? Seems that I can't turn off anti-aliasing without getting the current graphics context (e.g. [disable anti-aliasing for UIBezierPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417410/disable-anti-aliasing-for-uibezierpath)). But as I know the current graphics context is only available in `drawRect`, which I again can't implement.

Comment: Again, this is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555889/black-background-in-uiview

Comment: Setting a clear background color and disabling anti-aliasing seems to work. Thank you again.